# Regex: Ignore trailing whitespace in capturing group

Tags: regex, c++11

I am writing a simple config file parser in C++11 and want to use a regex to pick out the key=value pairs from a text file.  I want to be able to support comments in this file, denoted by a # symbol.  So far I have the following:

```
^(\w+)\s*=\s*([^#]+)
```

This matches an alphanumeric parameter name starting at the beginning of the line, allows for optional whitespace around the = character and then captures everything up to a comment symbol.  This seems to work quite well, except for in the following example:

param_1 = test with comment # comment

The second capturing group captures the whitespace between the end of the parameter value and the # symbol.  Is there anyway I can get this to ignore any trailing whitespace in the second capturing group?

Comment: Which language/tool are you using?

Comment: I am using C++11 and std::regex_search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex works with your example :

```
^(\w+)\s*=\s*([^#\n]+?)\s*(?=#|$)
```

It is your original regex, modified to not be greedy for the second group, and match until whitespaces before a `#` or end-of-line are found.

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/zaJPGa/3)'s an example.