# Regex to capture text without leading or trailing whitespace

Tags: regex, rust

I have strings such as:

- `foo bar`
- `foo bar`
- `foo`
- `foo`

I want to write a regex to capture the inner text in a capture group and ignore any leading and trailing whitespace, i.e., match `foo bar` and `foo` respectively. Since I am doing this in Rust, I cannot use lookahead.

I tried `^\s*(.*)\s*$`. However, this includes the trailing whitespace in the capture group (since matching is greedy I guess).

Comment: or simply use [`str::trim()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.trim)

Comment: I believe this question is already asked many times in different ways

Comment: For various reasons, I did not want to use trim.

Comment: @AhmetEmrebas Similar questions exist, yes, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/q/41789461/11076036. But they are all more specific, and the answers did not help me. I tried to ask a better question by not just pasting my problem, but trimming it down to its core. In fact, https://stackoverflow.com/a/41789548/11076036 uses the lazy ? in its answer, but because it didn't explain it well enough, I didn't understand. So having matthew-e-brown's answer is actually super helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your original regex seems to work fine if you make the capturing group [*lazy*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2301298/10549827) with a `?`:

```
^\s*(.*?)\s*$
```

See here: https://regex101.com/r/bTRoG9/2

Comment: Nice, I didn't know this existed!

Comment: Note that this also matches an empty string.

Answer (score 2):

My solution was `^\s*(\S.*\S)\s*$`.

This elegantly uses `\S` (which matches any non-whitespace character) as left-most and right-most "guards". The first `\S` is technically not needed (`^\s*(.*\S)\s*$` works, too), but I like the symmetry and the explicit guards.

Comment: Note that `^\s*(\S.*\S)\s*$` matches at least 2 non whitspace characters.

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative:

```
\S(.*\S)?
```

Since regex captures left to right, this starts matching a substring at the 1st non-whitespace character, then uses an optional capture group to capture 0+ characters (greedy) upto the last possible non-whitespace char. See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/EKx22R/1)

Just refer to group 0 in your code.